# Why express Router changes path to static resources?

Tags: node.js, express

I`m having trouble, after I decided to extract my routes from main **app.js** to some **/routes/myRoute.js**. All my static resources started to be getting from the wrong path.

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//...
app.use('/re*', require('./routes/re'));
// ...
```

**/routes/re.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// example 127.0.0.1:3000/re/
router.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('perspectives/re');
}

// example 127.0.0.1:3000/re/page=2
router.get('/page=*', function(req, res){
   // some code
   res.redirect('/re');
}
```

**/perspectives/re.jade**

```
extends ../layout

block pageResources
  script(src='extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js')
  //...
```

jQuery.js stores on path: /**public/extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js**

**The problem!**
If I am navigating http://127.0.0.1:3000/re - everything seems ok!

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/re
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
...
```

But when I`m trying to go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/re/page=1 - than my server receives several requests:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/re/page=1
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/re/extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js   // wrong pass!
```

And I really don`t get why application searches the static resource there?

P.S. First ever post to StackOverFlow. Please don`t be very angry, if a question is too simple, or something is incorect

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the application searches the static resource under /re/ is that not the application but the browser requests `/re/extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js`.

To replay the request/response scenario of your browser:

1. Request the page

   GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/re/page=1
2. The browser receives

`//...
script(src='extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js')
//...`

3. The URL is relative so the browser builds a new absolute URL by using the current URL's scheme, host and parent path which is `/re/`.
4. This results in `http://127.0.0.1:3000/re/extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js`.

You could solve this issue by using an absolute URL in your jade template:

`//...
script(src='/extensions/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js')
//...`

Comment: Seems passing the absolute URL - is a solution. But I thought that there can be another way of solving this, like: 1) Pass my express application instance to the router, so that router would know where to get static resources. 2) Or pass static dirs to router similarly as I do for express app: `router.use(express.static(__somethingLikeARootDirName + '/public'));`

Comment: And by the way absolute pass is not a good solution for me, because my server can be running on different hosts, so getting host address from configure for each page is rather complecated, from code perspective. :(